# Tor will not restart or stop

Tags: configuration

When I run

`service tor stop`

The process is still running

If I run

`service tor restart`

and then

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep tor -i`

I get a lot of warnings and errors (see below). It seems it's trying 5 times. These records are repeated 5 times and restart counter increments up to 5

It seems that tor cannot be stopped or restarted.

How to make it to operate normally? Is it safe if I kill the process?

```
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32894]: Apr 12 13:51:39.762 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.3.3.
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32894]: Apr 12 13:51:39.762 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32894]: Apr 12 13:51:39.762 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32894]: Apr 12 13:51:39.762 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32894]: Configuration was valid
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.932 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.3.3.
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.932 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.932 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.932 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.935 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.935 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.935 [notice] Opening HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:9080
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.935 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9080: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.935 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject tor[32895]: Apr 12 13:51:39.935 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 12 13:51:39 myproject systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 12 13:51:40 myproject systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 12 13:51:40 myproject systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
```

Comment: It seems that tor is already running (probably outside of a service). You should kill all running tor processes and try restating the service. If that doesn't work, then please add more information to the question: How did you install tor? Are you running any other tor-related programs? What changes have you made to your tor configuration? Can you list all running tor processes? Etc.

Comment: I commented all changes in torrc.

I see the process like this
```/etc/tor# ps aux | grep tor```
```root      1155  0.0  0.0  16148  1060 pts/1    S+   19:42   0:00 grep --color=auto tor```

```debian-+ 13017  0.1  1.3 107520 52868 ?        S    Mar02  74:56 /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 1```

Comment: I finally killed the process and started again service tor start. Now everything is okay in syslog and when I restart tor I see pid is being changed.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it. It is okay to send a SIGINT or SIGTERM to tor, and it will shut down safely (SIGINT is preferable though).